# Why I cannot assign the rsqrt op value of a tensor to the Eigen::Tensor<T,0>

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

```
auto linear_square = linear * linear;
auto linear_square_sum = linear_square.sum().sqrt();
```

If I cout the value of linear_square_sum, I can see a number. Now I want to get the scalar value of linear_square.sum().sqrt(), so I give it the type Eigen::Tensor to be like the following code,

```
auto linear_square = linear * linear;
Eigen::Tensor<T,0> linear_square_sum = linear_square.sum().sqrt();
```

unfortunately, it gives some error. The actual type of linear_square.sum().sqrt() is

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrQGI.png)

and the error is

> external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorAssign.h:127:5:
>   error: static assertion failed: YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE
>   external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorAssign.h:
>   In instantiation of 'Eigen::TensorEvaluator,
>   Device>::TensorEvaluator(const XprType&, const Device&) [with
>   LeftArgType = Eigen::TensorFixedSize, 0, long int>; RightArgType =
>   const Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp, const Eigen::TensorReductionOp, const
>   Eigen::DimensionList, const Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const
>   Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0, Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer>
>
> > , const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0, Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> > >, Eigen::MakePointer> >; Device =
> >     Eigen::DefaultDevice; Eigen::TensorEvaluator, Device>::XprType =
> >     Eigen::TensorAssignOp, 0, long int>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp,
> >     const Eigen::TensorReductionOp, const Eigen::DimensionList, const
> >     Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0,
> >     Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const
> >     Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0, Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >
> >     , Eigen::MakePointer> > >]': external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorExecutor.h:88:41:
> >     required from 'static void Eigen::internal::TensorExecutor::run(const
> >     Expression&, const Device&) [with Expression = const
> >     Eigen::TensorAssignOp, 0, long int>, const Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp,
> >     const Eigen::TensorReductionOp, const Eigen::DimensionList, const
> >     Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0,
> >     Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const
> >     Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0, Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >
> >     , Eigen::MakePointer> > >; Device = Eigen::DefaultDevice; bool Vectorizable = false; bool Tileable = false]'
> >     external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorFixedSize.h:328:65:
> >     required from 'Eigen::TensorFixedSize::TensorFixedSize(const
> >     Eigen::TensorBase&) [with OtherDerived = Eigen::TensorCwiseUnaryOp,
> >     const Eigen::TensorReductionOp, const Eigen::DimensionList, const
> >     Eigen::TensorCwiseBinaryOp, const Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0,
> >     Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >, const
> >     Eigen::TensorChippingOp<0, Eigen::TensorMap, 16, Eigen::MakePointer> >
> >     , Eigen::MakePointer> >; Scalar_ = Eigen::half; Dimensions_ = Eigen::Sizes<0>; int Options_ = 0; IndexType = long int]'
> >     tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc:2871:13: required from 'void
> >     tensorflow::SparseApplyGFtrlOp::Compute(tensorflow::OpKernelContext*)
> >     [with Device = Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice; T = Eigen::half; Tindex = long
> >     long int; bool has_l2_shrinkage = false]'
> >     tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc:4684:1: required from here
> >     external/eigen_archive/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorAssign.h:127:5:
> >     error: static assertion failed: YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE Target
> >     //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build

Comment: What is the type of `linear` and `T`?

Comment: Just a wild guess: `auto` does not play well with expression templates.

Comment: @Gilles-Philippe Paillé originally, the tensor A is `Eigen::Tensor<T,2,1,long int>`. Then A is chipped into slices. I get one slice and named it linear. The whole process can be seen in https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrQGI.png, with the `TensorMap` in the most inner, then the `TensorChippingOp`, coming the `TensorwiseBinaryOp` meaning the muplication of linear * linear, then the `sumReducer` is the linear_square.sum() process, and finally the `scalar_rsqrt_op` is the process of linear_square.sum().sqrt()

Comment: @L. F. `auto` almost makes me crazy

Comment: @Gilles-Philippe T is the template parameter, that is initialized as `double` which can be seen in the https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrQGI.png

Comment: From the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) "*In short: do not use the auto keywords with Eigen's expressions, unless you are 100% sure about what you are doing"*.

Comment: @RHertel I'm quite sure that finally I will get a scala value because of the operation of `.sum().sqrt()`, in which `.sum()` is the sum of all dimensions. So the type of final value should be Tensor(T,0). But the interpreter just doesn't buy it

Comment: Do not post images to (parts of) code/error messages. Provide a [mre]!

Comment: I'm almost entirely sure that  `.sum()` will return a scalar T  (presumably a double or some such), which doesn't have a `.sqrt()` overload.